# how can i render base.html in one app's view?

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

i want create a footer info model and use base.html in static folder and why its not work?

models.py

```
class FooterContactInfo(models.Model):
    phoneumber1=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    phoneumber2=models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email_help =models.EmailField()
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
def FooterContactInfo_view(request):
    footer = FooterContactInfo.objects.all().last()
    return render(request, 'base.html',context={'footer':footer})
```

base.html

```
     <li>
          <a href="#0"><i class="fas fa-phone-alt"></i>{{footer.phoneumber1}}</a>
     </li>
   <li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class FooterInfo:
    def __init__(self, copyright_year: int, company_name: str):
        self.copyright_year = copyright_year
        self.company_name = company_name

    def get_copyright_notice(self) -> str:
        return f"Copyright {self.copyright_year} {self.company_name}"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).